# yank into register also yank to the default one after upgrading to MacOS Sierra

Tags: vim

If I remember correctly, before updating,
`"+y` will yank into the system clipboard, but it will not affect the register that `p` is using.

After updating it does.

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the `clipboard` option. To see what it's set to, run:

```
:set clipboard?
```

This can have a number of values, including combinations. If it's `unnamed`, then `p`, `y`, etc. will use the `*` register. If it's `unnamedplus`, then they'll use the `+` register. There are other values and combinations (see `:help 'clipboard'` (include the quotes)).

It's likely that yours is now set to `unnamedplus`, or possibly a combination (`unnamed,unnamedplus`, which would put it in both `*` and `+`).

If you don't want `"+y` affecting the default `p` register, put this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Comment: I checked `set clipboard` but actually the setting is empty. And after setting it to `unnamed` `"+y` still yank into `""` register.